# Can 'nix handle NTFS ADS data streams?

Tags: ntfs

Two-three years ago, I experimented (in Windows) with NTFS ADS meta-data ([Alternate Data Streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29)).  It seemed like an interesting idea, but it is certainly not "portable".

Is there an NTFS-ADS aware tool which can read and/or write this ADS data?
Also, do any of the `nix commonly used/preferred file-syystems support similar secondary streams"?

Comment: Related: [Can I read and write to alternate HFS+ file forks or NTFS data streams from Linux?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57987)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ntfs-3g FUSE driver (almost certainly the one you're using if you've got read/write) talks ADS, but not by default (except on Linux apparently, where ADS are mapped to extended attributes by default).

From ntfs-3g's [man page](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-manual/#5):

> **Alternate Data Streams (ADS)**
>
> NTFS stores all data in streams. Every
>   file has exactly one unnamed data
>   stream and can have many named data
>   streams. The size of a file is the
>   size of its unnamed data stream. By
>   default, ntfs-3g will only read the
>   unnamed data stream.
>
> By using the
>   options "streams_interface=windows",
>   you will be able to read any named
>   data streams, simply by specifying the
>   stream's name after a colon. For
>   example:
>
> cat some.mp3:artist
>
> Named data streams act like normal
>   files, so you can read from them,
>   write to them and even delete them
>   (using rm). You can list all the named
>   data streams a file has by getting the
>   "ntfs.streams.list" extended
>   attribute.

As for the flip-side of your question, the basic umbrella term for this extra metadata would be [extended file attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes). The various unices and their filesystems have support for this kind of thing under various names: the ext* family and many other Linux fs's call these *xattrs*.

Comment: Okay, thanks *zerocrates*...  (I've added a minor update to my queston: I experimented in the Windows environment itself)...  Either way, you've answered the question fully...